# Sparql Query slower in local DBPedia than in Online API

Tags: query-optimization, sparql

I am getting this strange behavior from my local Virtuoso dbpedia setup. Following query is slower in my local version of dbpedia then in online api[http://dbpedia.org/sparql].

```
SELECT distinct ?p WHERE { ?url1 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/GovernmentAgency> . ?url2 rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Town> .
{?url1 ?p ?url2 .} UNION {?url2 ?p ?url1 .}}
```

Also, I checked with other queries and they are relatively faster in local than in online sparql.

What could be the possible reasons and fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

### Warning: This is not a good and helpful answer

"Online API" is what? The public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint? It's not clear which triple store you use on your local machine. The public endpoint is using Virtuoso.

Let me give you some points to consider:

1. If you're also using Virtuoso

   - The public endpoint is using the cluster edition of Virtuoso, thus, might have better performance regarding intra- and inter-query parallelization
   - The server on which it's deployed might have more resources than your "local" setup (which is unknown)
   - The Virtuoso setup might be different from your setup
   - The public endpoint might have loaded much more data, thus, other queries might be faster on your machine
2. If you're using a different triple store

   - comparison of performance is much more difficult since triple stores might perform better on different queries
   - The server on which it's deployed might have more resources than your "local" setup (which is unknown)

Indeed, there might be many other reasons ...

Possible and most obvious "fix": Assign more resources to your local triple store, in particular, use an SSD, more main memory, etc.
And of course, the configuration of the triple store is important, which indeed depends on the triple store.

Comment: I am using 32GB Ram and SSD for data storage. Every other query is better except this particular query.